# call function pass value of div as parameter

Tags: angularjs, function, console

I need to call a function from my html page then using the div content as the parameter.

Angular Code (.js file)

```
 $scope.foo = function(url) {
     console.log(url);
  };
```

.html file

```
 <span ng-click="foo(t.ticketId)">
   <div>
    ThisIsTheOutput
   </div>
</span>
```

what i am getting now is undefined. Help please!!

Comment: is t.tickedId defined? I need more info to see what is wrong

Comment: yes it already has a value.. lets just assume the t.ticketid  = abc